# Enumeration variables can't be set to values, are always <undefined value> in C++/CLI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have a global enumeration

```
enum class CColour{
     BLACK,
     WHITE,
     GOLD
};
```

that has its own headerfile CColour.h wich is included in stdafx.h

I was trying to fix some bugs (EDIT: I'm done with that) and encountered the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    [...]
    CColour colour1 = WHITE;
    [...]
}
```

I've set a watch to colour1 in Visual Studio, and I have some other functions using CColour too, but in the watch it is always displayed as `<undefined value>` with no type specifier. (and a small lock next to the icon, don't know if that's relevant)

this seems strange because every function that uses CColour works perfectly fine.

can anybody explain why that is and how to fix it?

Comment: It shows a period "." in the watch window for `colour1`?  Maybe a screenshot  of the watch window would help us understand.

Comment: It shows `<undefined value>`, he didn't quote the `<>` properly.

Comment: Use the **enum class** keyword to create a managed enum.  Declaring an unmanaged enum public makes no sense.  Ought to generate a compile error but doesn't.

Comment: @Matt Smith sorry, it literally shows "<undefined value>" in the watch with no type specifier...

Comment: @Hans Passant that's how CColour originally was defined, I changed it back. but that didn't help :/

Comment: Just an idea like that: shouldn't `WHITE` be scoped? Like `CColour::WHITE` or something? And beware whether ALL_CAPS identifiers are already defined as a macro...